# Accessing a protected value of a superclass argument in a subclass of the superclass

Tags: scala, inheritance

In the following Scala code, `B` extends `A`, and also takes `A` as an argument in its constructor. `B` can access `foo` from the superclass, but not from the superclass object passed in.

```
class A() {
    protected val foo = 1
}

class B(a: A) extends A {
    println(foo)   // okay
    println(a.foo) // fail - "access to protected value foo not permitted"
}
```

Is there a way to successfully get `a.foo` in `B` without using reflection and without changing the modifier to `protected[package]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification (linked in chengpohi's answer) says:

> A protected identifier x may be used as a member name in a selection r.x
>   only if one of the following applies:
>
> - The access is within the template defining the member, or, if a qualification C is given, inside the package C, or the class C, or its companion module, or
> - r is one of the reserved words this and super, or
> - r's type conforms to a type-instance of the class which contains the access.

The first says that `foo` can be accessed in `A` itself (the second part doesn't apply because you don't use `protected[C]`) and so doesn't help you.

The second doesn't apply.

The third says that the receiver's type (which is `A` in this case) must conform to `B`, which it doesn't.

So none of the three conditions apply, the access is illegal, and you must change one of the above factors to make it legal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [package protected](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#protected) to declare variable, so it can be used under the current package, example:

```
package foobar {
  class A {
    //package protected variable
    protected[foobar] val foo = 1
  }
  class B(a: A) extends A {
    println(foo) // okay
    println(a.foo) // fail - "access to protected value foo not permitted"
  }
}
import foobar._
val b = new B(new A)
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand I can do that, and wanted to know if it's possible without changing the modifier. I've updated the my question.

Comment: @flamecto, need to clear that `protected` is only can be accessed it's subclass and modifier like the above. so there should no other way to access the `foo` other than using **reflection**.